no implicit conversion of nil into String - puppet
I am getting this error while using a dsc resource on puppet and getting an error "no implicit conversion of nil into String" during runtime.
Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: no implicit conversion of nil into String
Any idea, what I might be missing?
Here is the link to the resource https://github.com/dsccommunity/SqlServerDsc/wiki/SqlWaitForAG
dsc { 'WaitForAG':
  resource_name => 'SqlWaitForAG',
  module        => 'SqlServerDsc',
  properties    => {
    name                 => $ag_name,
    servername           => $server_name,
    instancename         => 'MSSQLSERVER',
    retryintervalsec     => 300,
    retrycount           => 24,
    psdscrunascredential => {
      'dsc_type'       => 'MSFT_Credential',
      'dsc_properties' => {
        'user'     => $credential_network_access[username],
        'password' => Sensitive($credential_network_access[password]),
      },
    },
  },
  require       => [Dsc['HADREndpoint']],
}


Could you add the actual error message for additional context?

Hi @16c7x Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: no implicit conversion of nil into String

You appear to have linked to a project providing the physical resource you are trying to manage, but I don't see any documentation of the dsc Puppet resource type you are using to manage it.  Is that from the puppetlabs/dsc module, which seems abandoned?

Actually, I don't see it in puppetlabs/dsc, so maybe it's puppetlabs/dsc_lite? You really shouldn't make us work so hard to figure out what you're talking about.

Are there any lines before or after "Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: no implicit conversion of nil into String" maybe saying "at line..." or "in class..." It's useful to give the whole error message as there are sometimes clues in the lines before or after the error message.

No that’s the entire error msg

The resource declaration presented in the question is syntactically correct Puppet DSL.  You would get a different error message if it were not.
If I am correct in guessing that your dsc resource type is the one provided by the puppetlabs/dsc_lite module, then I can confirm that the form of the declaration looks consistent with that module's documentation.  I cannot judge whether the specific parameter values expressed are appropriate, but see below.
This message ...

Could not set 'present' on ensure: no implicit conversion of nil into String

... is undoubtedly an error message originating from the Ruby implementation of a custom resource type.  If you are right in associating it with the resource declaration in the question, then that would seem to implicate the dsc type itself. I would account it as reflecting flaw in that type.
At minimum, even if the issue revolves around the details of the resource properties you have declared, the diagnostic message that reaches you is entirely unhelpful and should be improved.  However, the specific error message could well indicate an intrinsic flaw in the module, for which there might or might not be an available workaround.
Therefore,

make sure you're using the latest release of the Puppet module providing the affected Puppet resource type.
If the problem is present in that release then you should probably raise an issue against that module.


Yeah, makes sense, my bad I missed to mention dsc_lite in the description, https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-dsc_lite/blob/main/REFERENCE.md

If any of your variables are not defined properly, Puppet uses nil by default which cannot be converted to type String unless if you do it explicitly in the code.
So check the values of $ag_name, $server_name, and $credential_network_access to ensure they have a value. You can also define the values explicitly at the beginning of your file.
In order to debug your code you can add notify statements to log the values of the varaibles to check if they are set correctly:
notify { "ag_name: ${ag_name}": }
notify { "server_name: ${server_name}": }
notify { "credential_network_access: ${credential_network_access}": }


nil is not a Puppet thing.  Perhaps you're confusing Puppet DSL with the Ruby in which the catalog builder and agent are implemented.  The Puppet analog of Ruby nil is undef.  Moreover, Puppet can implicitly stringify undef.  Doing so produces an empty string.
